# how to read csv columns in different order in spring batch with spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

i am creating a spring batch application that reads the csv file and store in db.

i am able to read it and store in db only when i set column names in order.

its not working when i change the order in csv file.

**My Objective:**

My objective is that to read the file and store in db even if column names are not in order.

My CSv File looks like this:

```
id,name
1,xyz
```

Above order is working as expected. but if changes the order like below, it s not working. how can i solve it?

```
name,id
xyz,1
```

**My Batch Configuration:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class SpringBatchConfiguration {


    @Bean
    public Job job(JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory,StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory,
            ItemReader<BatchProcessEntity> itemReader,ItemWriter<BatchProcessEntity> itemWriter,ItemProcessor<BatchProcessEntity,BatchProcessEntity> itemProcessor) {

        Step step = stepBuilderFactory.get("Loading-file")
                    .<BatchProcessEntity,BatchProcessEntity>chunk(100)
                    .reader(itemReader)
                    .processor(itemProcessor)
                    .writer(itemWriter)
                    .build();

        Job job=jobBuilderFactory.get("Csv")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .start(step).build();

        return job;

    }

    @Bean
    public FlatFileItemReader<BatchProcessEntity> flatFileItemReader(@Value("${input}") Resource resource) {

        FlatFileItemReader<BatchProcessEntity> flatFileItemReader=new FlatFileItemReader<>();

        flatFileItemReader.setResource(resource);
        flatFileItemReader.setName("Loading Csv File");
        flatFileItemReader.setLinesToSkip(1);
        flatFileItemReader.setLineMapper(lineMapper());

        return flatFileItemReader;

    }

    @Bean
    public LineMapper<BatchProcessEntity> lineMapper() {

        DefaultLineMapper<BatchProcessEntity> defLineMapper=new DefaultLineMapper<>();

        DelimitedLineTokenizer delimitedLineTokenizer=new DelimitedLineTokenizer();
        delimitedLineTokenizer.setDelimiter(",");
        delimitedLineTokenizer.setStrict(true);
        delimitedLineTokenizer.setNames(new String[] {"id","name"});


        BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<BatchProcessEntity> beanWrapperFieldSetMapper=new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<>();
        beanWrapperFieldSetMapper.setTargetType(BatchProcessEntity.class);


        defLineMapper.setLineTokenizer(delimitedLineTokenizer);
        defLineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(beanWrapperFieldSetMapper);

        return defLineMapper;
    }
}
```

**My Entity:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="springbatchprocess")
@Data
public class BatchProcessEntity {

@Id
Integer id;

@Column(name="name")
String eName;

@Column(name="address")
String eAddress;

@Column(name="salary")
String eSalary;

@Column(name="dept")
String eDept;

@Column(name="status")
Integer eStatus;

@Column(name="date")
Date date;

}
```

Above code is working fine only when i set columns in order as defined in code. when i change the order, its not working?

how can i solve it?

Comment: If you change the column order, you need to update the line mapper accordingly. If you want something dynamic, you would create a custom line mapper.

Answer (score -1):

You need to write a custom mapper to do this. There is an example of one provided here in this tutorial:

https://www.baeldung.com/introduction-to-spring-batch

It'd be something like this:

```
public class BatchProcessFieldSetMapper implements FieldSetMapper<BatchProcessEntity> {

    public BatchProcessEntity mapFieldSet(FieldSet fieldSet) throws BindException {

        BatchProcessEntity batchProcessEntity = new BatchProcessEntity();

        batchProcessEntity.setEAddress(fieldSet.readString("address"));

        //...etc

        return batchProcessEntity;
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not work. the lineTokenizer will still follow the order that you set in the lineTokenizer.setName(). So when The FieldSetMapper is called, the values from the tokenizer will already be in whatever order you set in the setNames() and thus producing the wrong result.